# What's the best way to handle Node.js flash messages?

Tags: node.js, express, pug, flash-message, connect-flash

I am a beginner with Node.js and i absolutely love it. I wonder how can i handle flash message the best and easiest way.

I used connect-flash package in my site. Does it have better ones?

I always put my flash messages in my render function like this:

```
res.render('auth/login', {
        title: 'Log in',
        success: req.flash('success'),
        error: req.flash('error')
    });
```

Does it have a way to handle the gloabally? like in the res.locals.messages variable or something like this?

I use JADE html templating, so i print them like #{success}. How can i access a global variable this way to print my flash messages?

Thank you very much for your help and advices!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set the `success` and `error` variables in every request, you can use `res.locals` like you mentioned. You can accomplish this with middleware that you'll include after `connect-flash`:

```
// ...

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  next();
});

// ...
```

Now, `success` and `error` will always be in every call to `res.render`.